# How to export from excel to MySql with dynamic fields inside

Tags: mysql, database, excel, import-from-excel

I have a problem,
I want to export from excel to MySql database table, but the destination table field is dynamic.
Let's say:

```
table A for storing field_information (e.g. field_name, field_type)
table B for storing field_answers (e.g. field_info_id, value)
```

example of excel spreadsheet file (which I convert into cvs format):

```
name,school,news;
"test","test_school","test_news";
```

I know I can export from excel to MySql (with static field) using following syntax:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '\\path' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

but, what if dynamic field?
How could I programmatically know which row of the spreadsheet should go to which database table? 
Anyone can help?Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How will you programmatically know which row of the spreadsheet should go to which database table? How about some example rows of the spreadsheet?

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly,
I'd sort the spreadsheet and then do two imports, to the two db tables.